# Show that $ \int_{0}^{\frac{1}{f}} e^{-j2\pi kft} \cdot e^{j2\pi lft} dt=0$ for $k,l \in \mathbb{Z}$ with $k \ne l$

Tags: integration, orthogonality, signal-processing

How can I show that:
$$\int\limits_{0}^{1/f} e^{-j2\pi kft} \cdot e^{j2\pi lft}dt=0 \qquad\forall(k,l) \in \mathbb{Z},\,k \ne l$$
I am not quite sure how to get from LHS to RHS. Can someone explain me the steps inbetween?

Comment: I think you're missing dt. Anyway, $e^ae^b=e^{a+b}$, and integrate directly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using what @Benjamin Wang mentioned, for the function you get:
$$f(t)=\exp\left[2\pi fj t(l-k)\right]\qquad t\in[0,1/f]$$
now since $(l-k)\in\mathbb{Z}$ we have an integer multiple of a period happening over the integral, and the integral over a single period is zero, and so the integral must be zero. The exception being $l=k$ where $f(t)=1\forall t$ and so we negate this